# pgAdmin tables not refreshing

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've created 4 tables in query tool but the tables are not listed under schema.

Tables are returned successfully & I've refreshed everything several times. I'm super new to this, what am I missing? As easy-to-explain as possible, thanks in advance.

Screenshot of issue

[image: 1]

Comment: Try to run SHOW TABLES. See if that shows up the tables

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I had two instances running. I shut one down and it worked :) Sometimes it's the obvious things that aren't so obvious. Appreciate it!